# std::unique_ptr destructor constructor order

Tags: c++, std

I want to know when I assign new unique_ptr to prior unique_ptr, what happens. In the below code :

```
std::unique_ptr<my_class> test;
......
test = std::unique_ptr<my_class>(new my_class());
......
test = std::unique_ptr<my_class>(new my_class());
```

I expected that when for second time I assign a new std::unique_ptr to test, first destructor of my_class called then constructor of it called. **is it wrong what I expected?**
but when I debug my code what I see is inverse. First constructor of my_class called then destructor of it called.

Comment: @seccpur yes i do it now but i want to know why this happen

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the second constructor call threw an exception? BTW: The `unique_ptr` in your question is a red herring, there are no special rules that apply here.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt constructor or destructor can't throw exception.

Comment: Nice guess, but wrong.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The short answer is, throwing stuff in the constructor is dangerous. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824540/throw-exception-in-constructor-c). i don't remember but i read in some books that never throw exception in constructor or destructor.

Comment: Sorry, that answer is rubbish. The constructor must establish class invariants that are required to give guarantees on the functioning of that class. If it can't establish those, it must throw. Of course, you can add one more potential state to your class that means it's defunct, but that would have to be checked in each and every place before the instance is used. Would you like to check your string instances whether they are valid? Probably not, that's why either the string initializes or throws.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt how release the partial memory that the constructor allocate when it throw exception?

Comment: Read the discussion that follow the answer. It's use of raw pointers that is the fault.  If you do, you need to pay extra attention to not leak memory which required additional code. If you use smart pointers, you get a guaranteed cleanup even in the face of exceptions.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it is right. i change my sentence to :it is better to don't throw exception from constructor or destructor.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Never throw while being the direct owner of an object.[link](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#e13-never-throw-while-being-the-direct-owner-of-an-object)

Comment: That could be rephrased to: Avoid being the direct owner of an object, use smart pointers instead. Still, you can throw even in that situation, you just need to write additional code to release the object first. BTW: Constructors and destructors are very different concerning their exception usage, I'm only talking about constructors here!

Comment: @nadar I agree that destructors *should* not throw exceptions. But for constructors, throwing an exception is the only really elegant way available for signalling error/failure to construct.

Comment: I wish we had `std::unique_ptr::emplace(...)` to do what you want to do. `std::variant` has `emplace`, which destructs the old object before constructing the new one.

Comment: @Bernard yep, it's nice idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the constructor is invoked before the destructor of the previous instance, is because you're passing `new my_class()` as an argument to the unique_ptr's constructor. The argument is evaluated first, constructing a new unique_ptr instance which takes ownership of the newly created object, then that new unique_ptr instance is assigned to the old.

As a result, the old unique_ptr's my_class object it had ownership of will be deallocated and destructed, invoking the my_class destructor.

It's effectively the same as if you had written:

```
my_class* temp = new my_class;
test = std::unque_ptr<my_class>(std::move(temp));
```

Here it's directly visible that the new object is constructed first.

Answer (score 4):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D):

> `unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr&& r ) noexcept;` (1)
>   `template< class> U, class E > unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr<U,E>&& r ) noexcept;`
>   (1)
>
> Transfers ownership from `r` to `*this` as if by calling
>   `reset(r.release())` followed by an assignment of `get_deleter()` from
>   `std::forward<E>(r.get_deleter())`.

As you can see [reset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) is called on the previous pointer, which does the following:

> 1. Saves a copy of the current pointer `old_ptr = current_ptr`
> 2. Overwrites the current pointer with the argument `current_ptr = ptr`
> 3. If the old pointer was non-empty, deletes the previously managed object
>      `if(old_ptr != nullptr) get_deleter()(old_ptr)`.

Comment: @nader added to the answer